# WMS and WFS Services in MapServer

Tags: openlayers, wms, wfs, mapserver, map-service

I am new to MapServer. I was trying to get `WMS` and `WFS` services started but could not get any simple article to start the services from scratch and display service data into OpenLayers.

Please suggest some simple articles to start the WMS and WFS services on MapServer and use them in OpenLayers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

there is a topic [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/18364/setting-up-mapserver-wms-and-use-it-with-openlayers) which is the same as your question but i dont know whether works or not for you..
you can read this articles for getting some information....

1.Setting Up a WMS Server Using MapServer [here](http://mapserver.org/ogc/wms_server.html#setting-up-a-wms-server-using-mapserver)...

2.Open Layer with MapSever [here](http://khayer.wordpress.com/2010/07/14/open-layer-with-mapsever/)

3.Mapserver WMS Settings [here](http://khayer.wordpress.com/2010/07/07/mapserver-wms/)

4.Overlay WMS on Google in OpenLayers [here](http://blog.sumbera.com/2010/02/17/overlay-wms-on-google-in-openlayers/)

i hope it helps you...